# output one instance of a data set that could have multiple occurrences

Tags: php, mysql

I am having problems sifting through a MySQL query I am trying to strip. I am trying to basically take a column, pull every single entry for that column in a table and then strip it to only show one occurrence even if it happens more than once. So if the value of "bob" shows up more than once I only want it to output once, Everything I have tried either makes it so nothing outputs, or it still outputs ever occurrence of it.

My Code:

```
 $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT org FROM accounts");
                     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                        $holder = array();
                        $validate = false;
                        array_push($holder, $row['org']);
                        for ($i=0; $i <= count($holder); $i++) { 
                            if($holder[$i]!=$row['org']){
                                $validate =  true;
                            }
                        }
                        if ($validate){
                        ?>
                        <option><?php echo $row['org']?></option>
                        <?php
                        }   
                     }
```

Comment: That's what [DISTINCT](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx) is for.

Comment: Thanks Christian, that was exactly what I needed. Did not know about that, and will make a permanent note, thanks for the quick response!

Comment: no worries, I've actually written an answer with two methods you can try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a php function called [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) which lets you search through an array for a specific value without having to write your own loop. So you could replace your entire loop with something like this:

```
if ( ! in_array( $row['org'], $holder ) )
    // your code here
```

However, your problem is that you're re-initialising the `$holder` variable to a blank array for every row. You need to store that variable *outside* the while loop if you wanted to use the above method. For example:

```
 $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT org FROM accounts");
 $holder = array();
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    if ( ! in_array( $row['org'], $holder ) ) {
        array_push($holder, $row['org']);

        ?>
        <option><?php echo $row['org']?></option>
        <?php  
    }
 }
```

However, you can also select [DISTINCT](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx) values from a MySQL query, which is probably what you want to do:

```
 $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT org FROM accounts");
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    ?>
    <option><?php echo $row['org']?></option>
    <?php
 }
```